# How do I take a certain word from user input and make it a string?

Tags: c#, console, readline

I am wondering how I take a certain word from a sentence typed into a console and define it as a string. If anyone could explain how I do this I would be very greatful.

User Input = This is a red ball. 
string ballcolour = red
I want to take the third word from this sentence and make it a string but do not know how. I only know so far how to make a string equal the console readline.

- Maximus

Comment: The string class has a method named Split that could break your whole string in its parts creating an array of words. Look at [examples of string.Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: Don't take stuff from users! -- That's impolite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string color = userInput.Split(' ')[2];
```

Of course, in a real program, you should check if the string has 3 words before trying to get it from the array returning from the Split() method, something like this:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] words = userInput.Split(' ');
if (words.Length >= 3) {
    string color = words[2];
    Console.WriteLine("The third word is: " + color);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Not enough words.");
}
```

Comment: Note that you would also want to split on '.' and perhaps other punctuation so that the last word isn't "ball."  What you are proposing isn't quite as straight forward as you may think.

Comment: Yes I know that, you can go even further, but probably he is starting to learn so I tried to stay simple.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
//this will break the user input into an array
var inputBits = userInput.Split(' ');
//you can now directly access the index of the word you seek
var color = inputBits[2];
//You can also iterate over it and do something else...
for(int i = 0; i < inputBits.Length; i++)
{
    var inputBit = inputBits[i];
    //do something else
}
```